# Set both bounds and tilt in google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to set at the same time tilt and bounds to th camera in my map.

So I think I need this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

but I don't know how can I add also tilt.

If I try to insert other code, like this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(mMap.getCameraPosition().target)
                            .zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                            .bearing(30)
                            .tilt(45)
                            .build()));
```

only the second animation is done. So, the tilt is applied, but I have not the correct bounds.

So, the question, as said in the question's title: how can I set both tilt and bounds for my camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you wait for the first animation with the bounds to complete, then animate the tilt when it finishes?

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50), 
        new CancelableCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder(mMap.getCameraPosition())
                                .bearing(30)
                                .tilt(45)
                                .build()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: There is still no better way to do it?